# python script to decrypt RSA message

Tags: python, encryption

I am writing a python script to decrypt a RSA encrypted message, first the message was encrypted in hex, and the key the same, so what I did was transform both of these from hex to base64 like this:

Key:

```
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
```

to:

```
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
```

and message:

```
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
```

to:

```
TAYF6QGwnXXF9b7+dDjXJG+YhTHMejmlnyS5SI1H366fyL61EX80oxb5OAYHvyObpuyoTaR6EtcgmGqKAQCn6dcCjX5CNVcFW54lDycdZDYBjFjnmo8musEHaHdvBtwXht10KLPERbiZPohGMLNsstMA+l3B/g66nkMwYtnYpY8zv2+TqjcpilcDzL9xyTrepEfwGOn3W7Q9vFKM/JvthlqbpD+SYHHavInMyi4ADxqWaFXMmBbkXAET7bVacAGY00apBIe1/xGRmUlz6xtSUrIsZBCqcOpOnD69Ro7yc9fPnRW1gkJEzSXyUohtHt/i1vLKpdXgD9hFl+PeGS20Gw==
```

Okay, then I transformed the base64 message into a raw data message using:

`cat secret | base64 -d > rawsecret`

Now I have a rawsecret and a key in the correct form I think, right?

So I began and wrote this script:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import base64
import zlib

def decrypt_blob(encrypted_blob, private_key):

    rsakey = RSA.importKey(private_key)
    rsakey = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsakey)

    encrypted_blob = base64.b64decode(encrypted_blob)

    chunk_size = 2048
    offset = 0
    decrypted = ""

    while offset < len(encrypted_blob):
        chunk = encrypted_blob[offset: offset + chunk_size]

        decrypted += rsakey.decrypt(chunk)

        offset += chunk_size


    return zlib.decompress(decrypted)

fd = open("rawkey.pem", "rb")
key = fd.read()
fd.close()

fd = open("rawsecret", "rb")
encrypted_blob = fd.read()
fd.close()

print decrypt_blob(encrypted_blob, key)
```

however I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "decrypt.py", line 35, in 
print decrypt_blob(encrypted_blob, key)
File "decrypt.py", line 20, in decrypt_blob
decrypted += rsakey.decrypt(chunk)

and Ciphertext with incorrect lentgh. why is that?

Comment: There are terminology error, as; `first message encrypted in hex`, no the output encoded as hex. The python library doesn't accept Base64, see at [doc](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html)

Comment: @kelalaka okay, if it doesn't accept Base64, then what should I use?

Comment: @kelalaka no, everything I listed here is everything I have

Comment: @kelalaka What do you think would be the best format for me to choose? Also do I have to transform the key and the message into that format or only one of those 2?

Comment: @kelalaka yes, indeed, is something similar to a CTF

Comment: @kelalaka so do you think there might be a possibility that the key and the message are inverted? I don't really think that, it is just big, or "too" big?

Comment: The Hex contaions the modulus and the private key. One must find the correct encoding, Pem,DER etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186006/discussion-between-c-cristi-and-kelalaka).

Comment: @kelalaka Can you guide me more? I've found the integers but don't know what to do now + they are too long

Comment: @kelalaka Now what do I do with the message, it's still in hex? Do I have to use ASN1 on it, too?

Comment: Yes, the RSA modulus is 2049, they should be long. Read the [documentation](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html) now. Are you sure it is using PKCS1_OAEP padding scheme?

Comment: @kelalaka I guess it is

Comment: But it isn't. It doesn't use any padding scheme, think raw RSA. First and only hint.